# python crashed two times while large matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, crash, matrix-multiplication, canopy

I have two matrices with following size m=(15715, 203) n=(203, 16384) .I am doing matrix multiplication in python, code is as shown I am using canopy software to run this code but before completion it is taking lots of memory space and crashing please can anyone help regarding this issue?

```
  import pandas as pd
m = pd.read_csv("Pmatrix.csv")
row0=m.shape[0]
len0=len(m.columns)
print row0
print len0

n = pd.read_csv("Qmatrix.csv")
row1=n.shape[0]
len1=len(n.columns)

print row1
print len1


def matrixmult (A, B):
    row0 = m.shape[0]

    len0 = len(m.columns)
    row1 = n.shape[0]
    len1 = len(n.columns)

    if len0 != row1:
      print "Cannot multiply the two matrices. Incorrect dimensions."
      Y=A.shape
      Z=B.shape
      print Y
      print Z

      return

    # Create the result matrix
    # Dimensions would be row0 x len1
    C = [[0 for row in range(len1)] for col in range(row0)]
    print C

    for i in range(row0):
        for j in range(len1):
            for k in range(len0):
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
    return C
```

Comment: use python 64bit ? the problem is that pandas is built on numpy ... numpy requires contiguous memory blocks, which are harder to come by ... and 32 bit systems (and by proxy python 32 bit) limit each application to 2 gb of total memory use ...

Comment: I am using python 64bit, but still facing the issue my Ram is 4 gb

Comment: numpy has `dot(A, B)` to multiplicate matricies.

Comment: do you get error message?

Comment: I did not get error message . I tried dot(m,n) i am getting the following output           {dot(m,n)
Out[2]: 
array([[   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       ..., 
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0, 8000,    0, ..., 8000,    0, 8000]])
}    is there a way in which i can see the entire matrix because as shown i can only see few values separated by commas

Comment: Just store the result back as a CSV...

Comment: Or extract subsets of the product result[20:40,20:40] etc to view / browse. Or use matplotlib to make a heatmap of the result.

Comment: Thanks Storing file back as Csv helped